# Nested async/await on Mongoose queries

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

I have an `async` function that needs to return an array of user_ids. My code is like:

```
async function getUserIds(option) {
  let user_ids = [];

  if (option === 'test') {
    const departments = await Departments.find({}).exec()
      .catch(() => console.log('ERROR');

    console.log('BEFORE LOOP');

    await departments.forEach(async(dpt) => {
      const pop = await Populations.findOne({_id: dpt.id}) 
        .catch(() => console.log('ERROR');

      console.log('work...');

      if (pop && (pop.max > pop.min)) {    
        const _users = await User.find({_id: {$in: pop.ids}}).exec()
          .catch(() => console.log("ERROR");

        user_ids = user_ids.concat(_users.map((u) => u._id));
        console.log('finished work...');
      }
    });

    return user_ids;
}

async function main() {
    let user_ids = await getUserIds('test');
    console.log(user_ids);
}
```

Now this is always returning an empty array `[]` and I can see the console logs in an asynchronous way:

```
BEFORE LOOP
[]   --> the return 
work...
work...
work...
work...
work...
work...
finished work...
finished work...
work...
finished work...
work...
finished work...
finished work...
```

I guess this line `await departments.forEach(async(dpt) => {` is not really `"awaiting"` so what can I do, what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: `await departments.forEach` this line does nothing, replace it with `map` and do `await Promise.all([...])`

Comment: Did you make it work?

Answer (score 3):

The `async`/`await` are a sugar way to use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

> `async` is like `new Promise()` and `await` is as `.then()`.

Use `Promise.all()` to wait till all Promise's resolves before continue.

In your case you should use `Array.prototype.map()` instead of [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). `forEach()` returns `undefined` and you are using `await`. The `.map()` will return an Array of Promise's as:

```
// Using .map()
departments = [ Promise, Promise, Promise ] // await till all Promise resolves to go foward.

// Using .forEach()
departments = 'undefined' // nothing to await for.
```

```
await Promise.all(
        departments.map(async(dpt) => {
            const pop = await Populations.findOne({_id: dpt.id})
                .catch(() => console.log('ERROR');

            console.log('work...');

            if (pop && (pop.max > pop.min)) {    
                const _users = await User.find({_id: {$in: pop.ids}}).exec()
                    .catch(() => console.log("ERROR");

                user_ids = user_ids.concat(_users.map((u) => u._id));
                
                console.log('finished work...');
            }
       })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should await for department promises before returning the result from function. The line `forEach` does nothing in your case, either replace it with `map` or with `for of`

with `map` example

```
...
const promises = departments.map(async(dpt) => {
  const pop = await Populations.findOne({_id: dpt.id}) 
    .catch(() => console.log('ERROR');

  console.log('work...');

  if (pop && (pop.max > pop.min)) {    
    const _users = await User.find({_id: {$in: pop.ids}}).exec()
      .catch(() => console.log("ERROR");

    user_ids = user_ids.concat(_users.map((u) => u._id));
    console.log('finished work...');
  }
});

await Promise.all(promises)

return user_ids
```